# HR personal record/inventory

Tags: open-source, saas, human-resources

Looking for a HR application that can do the following

- Onboard new employee

  - link to contract templates to be sign
  - list of tasks to be taken and check list (eg. create email, procure equipment)
- Track inventory of items issued to employee (eg. security token, tools, devices)
- Track request, approval, creation, deletion of access
- User can be either linked to Active Directory (preferred) or as standalone account.
- record of each action taken
- access right to view different activities

The overall idea is to track the activities throughout the time of the staff is in the company.
The main purpose is to provide record in one place and to meet audit requirement for control.

If there are no specific software dedicated to this purpose, would like to learn of alternatives that can implement similar concept. (eg. using workflow tools)

SaaS is fine (budget about $200/year), though it is preferred that there is an option to run the application on-premise should it be needed.

An open source application that can be tailored to accomplish this would be great.

Any regulatory or security concern will be separately evaluated once the software is identified to be able to provide the functionality.

Comment: You should _ideally_ also specify any regulatory requirements regarding things like information security in your location - most have some and some are very strict.

Comment: `linked to AD ` - what is AD?  For which operating system do you wnat this? Do you have a budget, or must it be gratis?  Btw, check out https://sourceforge.net/

Comment: @SteveBarnes it is for process audit. There is no specific specification that is aimed at. The main desired features are in the points. The key is to help administrator to consolidate information in one place. This in turns demonstrate that steps are taken to control.

Comment: In the UK & USA **any** information stored on a computer regarding any employee has to be appropriately protected, access to it appropriately restricted, etc. This needs to be considered in any answers that meet your points but without knowing the regulatory framework, i.e. which contries, etc., it is difficult to answer.

Comment: @SteveBarnes thank you for your point. If the recommendation is SaaS, the the data protection will be assess on the provider. If a self-hosted software is recommended, the company that eventually runs the software will take the responsibility. This question is asking for software or service that has the functions. Nevertheless, I will update the concern.